# the dual variables are not unique in an optimal solution to the dual problem if primal problem has redundant constraints

Tags: optimization, programming

Show that in the transportation problem the linear equality constraints are not
linearly independent, and that in an optimal solution to the dual problem the
dual variables are not unique. Generalize this observation to any linear program having redundant equality constraints.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: This question is from my linear optimization class. I have no clues of solving it. I would appreciate it much for any assistance from anybody.

Comment: What is the transportation problem?

Comment: Thanks so much, but how can you verify that the conditions is still satisfied with the new optimal solution? I would appreciate your reply again.

Comment: see new edit. Usually it is common practice to comment below the answer directly.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Consider the optimization problem

$$\min c^Tx$$

subject to

$$ \begin{bmatrix} A \\ \lambda^TA\end{bmatrix} x= \begin{bmatrix} b \\ \lambda^Tb \end{bmatrix}$$

$$x \geq 0$$

where $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} $, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1}$.

The dual is $$\max p^Tb + q \lambda^Tb$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} p^T & q \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} A \\ \lambda^TA\end{bmatrix}\leq c $$

Suppose $(p^*,q^*)$ is an optimal solution for the dual, verify that $(p^*+\lambda, q^*-1)$ is another optimal solution.

As for the transportation problem, given the incidence matrix, you should be able to recover the last row given the first $m-1$ rows easily.

Edit: Verifying the new solution is still feasible for dual.

We already know that $$\begin{bmatrix} p^{*T} & q^* \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} A \\ \lambda^TA\end{bmatrix}=p^{*T}A+q^*\lambda^TA\leq c $$

Check that
$$\begin{bmatrix} (p^*+\lambda)^{T} & (q^*-1) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} A \\ \lambda^TA\end{bmatrix}=(p^{*}+\lambda )^TA+(q^*-1)\lambda^TA\leq c $$

Comment: Thanks so much. This is a perfect answer